Imperfekt vs Perfekt with modal verbs
I understand that in narrative/non-spoken speech the Perfekt is much more common than the Präteritum.
But I'm not sure to what extent this applies with dealing with modal verbs. For example:

Leider konnten wir uns nur kurz darüber unterhalten.

vs

Leider haben wir uns nur kurz darüber unterhalten können.

When writing a message or talking to someone directly, which is more natural?

Both are perfectly natural.
In most cases Perfekt and Präteritum have no difference in meaning. The main exception is when talking about the future "Morgen haben wir uns darüber dann kurz unterhalten können und ...".
That means that speakers may chose between the two variants according to preferences, which in most cases favour using Präteritum over Perfekt in modal verbs.
Brevity: Präteritum is always shorter than Perfekt, so there is a natural inclination to use Präteritum over Perfekt, if nothing else speaks against it.
Personal preferences: Some speakers almost never use Präteritum in spoken speech. You can use this to your advantage: Perfekt is never "wrong" in spoken German.
Familiarity with forms / Preference for certain verbs: Rare strong verbs are hard, even for Germans, so there might be slight reservations against using forms like hobt. This might lead to some preference to use one form over another for certain verbs. This is also what leads to the claim speakers would have a personal "list" of verbs where they use Präteritum over Perfekt, when in reality speakers use both forms for the same verbs.[1]
Narrative: Präteritum is the "narrative" form. The exact meaning of this is not so easy to explain, but aspects of this include 1) emotional distance to the story and 2) moving the focus of the conversation into the past. It is also used to talk about settings.
Order: German is a V2 language, this means that the second position of the sentence is filled with one verb, with the rest of the predicate being at the very end of the sentence. This second position is often filled with a modal verb. When you don't have another modal verb, using Perfekt means this position is filled with haben and using Präteritum means this position is filled with the main verb.
Since the second position is usually filled with a modal verb, the hearer is expecting one of the few modal verbs, like "sein", "haben", "können" etc — They are not expecting one of the most important bits of the sentence. German (and many other languages) have the tendency to move the most important part to the end of the sentence and Perfekt does just this.
Modal verbs: As you see, for modal verbs, most aspects are preferring Präteritum: Präteritum is shorter, the forms are well-known and we still have the information at the end of the sentence.


I understand that in narrative/non-spoken speech the Perfekt is much more common than the Präteritum.

No. You understood wrong. In narratives — e.g. fictional literature — Präteritum is the main tense. While Plusquamperfekt marks the past in that. In real life Präsens is the main tense while Perfekt marks the past in that.
But Northerners use Präteritum in place of Perfekt for real life events for the auxiliaries, the modals and some very common verbs as geben or kommen. The latter only in certain contexts. It's consistent both in speaking and their writing.
The more north a German speaker is from, the more verbs go on their personal list. In southern Germany and Austria it's only sein, and in Switzerland not even that one.

The question is not about the Ersatzinfinitiv. But no, the Ersatzinfinitiv is not preferred by Southerners. They use it but they sometimes also use the Partizip II with modals. Northerners never do that.

Yes. Doppeltes Perfekt instead of Plusquamperfekt is also common in the south.
